# mysql create a column using a variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, for-loop, sql-update

my idea is like this 'using sql variables'

Note: id not PK

```
1st query   `select @newvalues :=   (id - coalesce((select sum(minus) from tbl_name t2 where t2.id < t.id), 0)) from tbl_name t;` 

2nd query.  `update tbl_name set ab = @newvalues;`
```

could i get all the rows of @newvalues even though it is just a "select query variable"? because at the moment I could only get the last value of it which is 5.

```
    @newvalues          ID *not Primary key

     9 |  ----------->  9 |              
     8 |  ----------->  8 | 
     7 |  ----------->  7 | 
     6 |  ----------->  6 | 
     5 |  ----------->  5 | 
                   *transfer the row values of @newvalues to the column ID.
```

Comment: any comments/ help please. I would really appreciate it

Comment: php experts, please help. Newbie here.

Comment: I would recommend a new column named `superNewID` and run `UPDATE table set superNewID=(newID-minus) where id=id`. Once you have done this then delete the `ID` column and rename `superNewID` to just `ID`

Comment: Overall this seems like a horrible idea considering the general rule that ID's are supposed to be unique unless of course they are a Foreign Key but that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here? Is `ID` the primary key for this table? On the surface, this seems like a bad approach.

Comment: Also stop begging, it makes people want to delete your question more than help you. I debated saying anything at all when I saw your comments come through

Comment: sorry for name confusion, ID is not my primary key just an example. Im sorry.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sorry Sir

Comment: @MonkeyZeus my apology, I understand, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MikeBrant sorry for naming confusion, the ID there is not primary key. just for sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would need to get the row into an array in order to loop through it. To do so perform a query and store the results in a variable, then we will use the mysqli_fetch_array() function to turn the query into an array.

```
$idQuery = "SELECT * FROM table";
$idResult = mysqli_query(/*your database connection*/, $idQuery);
```

Now for the loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($idResult)) { 
$query = "UPDATE table SET ID = NewId WHERE id = " . $row['id'];
mysqli_query(/*your database connection*/, $query); }
```

This should work.

Comment: im still figuring it out, thanks nick. update you later

Comment: Okay, let me know if this solution works. If not I'll look into it more.

Comment: Ill just edit my code above for better illustration,

Comment: please take a look at the last part of the code above this webpage starting from 'my idea is like this'

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I do not have an answer for you. Best of luck!